# How can I initialize a vector in the initializer list of a varargs constructor?

Tags: c++, vector, constants, variadic-functions, initializer-list

I need to elaborate the constructor of the  following class:

```
class Foo {
public:
    const std::vector<Bar> bars;
    Foo(int num_bars, ...);
}
```

Assume for the sake of discussion that the extra argument are  all `const Bar&` or just `Bar`.

I need to initialize v on construction with the bars in the va_list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Make `Foo` a variadic template instead:

```
template <typename ...ArgumentTypes>
Foo(ArgumentTypes&& args...):
bars({std::forward<ArgumentTypes>(args)...})
{
}
```

This uses the initializer-list constructor of the vector.

Comment: What does the double-reference symbol mean in your example? Is there some kind of moving involved?

Comment: @einpoklum it's called a universal reference. It exploits the new reference collapsing rules to ensure the constructor can bind to both lvalues and rvalues. `std::forward` ensures that the lvalue/rvalue-ness of the inputs are correctly forwarded to the next function.